# ERROR TypeError: el is undefined Leaftlet AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, typeerror, undefined

I'm building an Angular app using leaflet, it's the first time i'm using such tool and i've read on here that you must add .remove() to your map Object if u don't want the "map container is already initialized" error, however, when i use setView i get the following error: [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o6ig.jpg);

This is the line that gives me such error:
`this.map = this.map.setView([this.cityLatitude, this.cityLongitude] ? [this.cityLatitude, this.cityLongitude] : window.alert("scegli una città dal dropdown"), 13);`

this is the entire code that gives me problem (i won't post the code of the whole component as it's really long): `this.map = this.map.remove(); this.map = this.map.setView([this.cityLatitude, this.cityLongitude] ? [this.cityLatitude, this.cityLongitude] : window.alert("scegli una città dal dropdown"), 13);`

This is coordinates format i'm trying to pass down to the function: ex: 45.438773145471984

Is that an incorrect format? am i doing something wrong? Should i pass coordinates in another format? Is the ternary operator the problem (if the two variables are null, show me an alert)?

Comment: You cannot reuse/use the map after calling `map.remove`, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-remove – "Destroys the map and clears all related event listeners"

Comment: Oh okok thanks, so if i want to just change the coordinates of the map and maybe add a marker, what should i do, without getting the  "map container is already initialized" error?